# Probability of "at least amount"

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I have 4 six-sided dice.  One of them has values of [0,0,3,3,3,4], and the other three have values of [0,0,0,1,1,2].  The first dice has a 2/3 chance of rolling at least a 3.  If I roll the other three dice together, what are the odds of rolling at least a three?

I don't know what to call this, but that is the best way I know how to ask that question.  I have many dice like this in a game I play and I'd like to do some analysis.  Mostly six-sided dice with values ranging from zero to four, but there are some ten-sided dice with values ranging from zero to four, so a general formula would be great.

So as a secondary question, I'd also like to solve that if I have a ten-sided dice with values [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,4,4], and three of the aforementioned [0,0,0,1,1,2] dice, what are the odds of rolling at least a sum of 5?

Thanks!

Comment: So are you asking "what is the probability that when I roll all four dice, at least one 3 comes up?" In that case, you could find the probability that no one gives a 3 and subtract this answer from 1 Since the other 3 cannot give a 3 face up, this should not be to difficult (no complement rule needed)

Comment: One could solve the three dice at least $3$ problem by an explicitly described calculation without much trouble. However, if you have quite a few of these kinds of problems, and they get substantially more complicated, simulation is likely to be the most reasonable approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We solve the problem of the probability of getting at least $3$ using three dice that have faces $(0,0,0,1,1,2)$. Mainly it is to illustrate technique.

It is easier to find the probability $p$ of getting a sum **less** than $3$, that is, a sum of $0$, $1$, or $2$. Then the answer to your problem is $1-p$.

The following are all the ways we could end up with sum $\le 2$:

(i) all $0$;

(ii) two $0$ and a $1$;

(iii) two $0$ and a $2$;

(iv) one $0$ and two $1$;

We find the probability of each and add up.

(i) The probability is $\left(\frac{3}{6}\right)^2$.

(ii) The die that shows a $1$ can be chosen in $3$ ways. The probability it shows a $1$ is $\frac{2}{6}$. The probability the other two show $0$ is $\left(\frac{3}{6}\right)^2$. Thus we get probability $3\cdot \frac{2}{6}\cdot \left(\frac{3}{6}\right)^2$.

(iii) Essentially the same reasoning gives $3\cdot \frac{1}{6}\cdot \left(\frac{3}{6}\right)^2$.

(iv) The reasoning is the same as for (ii). We get $3\cdot \frac{3}{6}\cdot \left(\frac{2}{6}\right)^2$.

Add all the above probabilities to get $p$. Then as mentioned earlier the answer to your problem is $1-p$.

**Remark:** If problems get much more complicated, and there are quite a few, simulation may be the way to go.